# Issue with Mongoose model.save callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am learning Node.js with a book. Instead of coping and using the book sample code as it is I am using the basis and reusing in own code used as learning exercise.

I have this code for a new user creation, I will copy what I believe are the relevant.
What I expect to happen is that user.register uses model.register and receive a true or false depending if the user was created or not and sending a response accordly

app.js capture the post

```
app.post('/user', users.actions.register);
```

user.js register

```
var register = function ( req, res ) {
    if ( req.body.username === '' || 
        req.body.email === '' || 
        req.body.password === '' ) {

        //Some field is blank - insufficient information
        console.log('User creation failure: Insufficient data');
        res.json(400);

    } else {

        var newUser = new models.account.user ({
            username: req.body.username,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password
        });

        models.account.register ( newUser, function (succ) {
            console.log (succ);
            if ( succ === true ) {
                res.json(200);
            } else {
                res.json(400);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

then account.register

```
var register = function ( newUser ) {
    console.log ('Save command sent.');
    newUser.save ( function ( err ) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return false;
        }
        console.log('User Created');
        return true;
    });
};
```

The user gets created on the database, and the output on the console is

```
Save command sent.
User Created
```

What I was expecting to happen is that succ receives true or false, but I am doing something wrong and cant figure out why.

I made this code works changing the approach, but since this is a learning experiment for me I wanted to be able to do it this way.

I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction or show me what I am doing wrong.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
models.account.register ( newUser, function (succ) {
    ...
}
```

you are passing an anonymous function as the second parameter to `register`. So, `register` has to accept that and invoke it with the results, like this

```
var register = function ( newUser, callBackFunction ) { // accept the callback
    console.log ('Save command sent.');
    newUser.save ( function ( err ) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return callBackFunction(false);  // invoke it on failure :(
        }
        console.log('User Created');
        return callBackFunction(true);       // invoke it on Success :)
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working as I was expecting now. So what I get from this is that I was using a callback that was not declared, and I was not returning it the right way. Probably I will need some more read about it, although I can see the error I am not fully understanding it. Again, thanks for the quick answer.